Conditions implying a matrix can be written non-trivially as Kronnecker product
Given a positive integer $n$ and an $n \times n$ real matrix $A$, what are some conditions to allow us determine if there exists (or there does not exist) real matrices $B$ and $C$ of appropriate size both strictly bigger than $1 \times 1$ such that $A = B \otimes C$ ?
If $n = 1$ or if $n$ is prime, then such $B$ and $C$ never exists.
So suppose that $n = ab = cd$, with $a >1$, $b>1$, $c > 1$ and $d > 1$. When $B$ has size $a \times c$ and $C$ has size $b \times d$, there is a possibility that $A = B \otimes C$. If $n$ only has one decomposition $n = ab$, then $B$ and $C$ are forced to be square matrices. So my question, stated more precisely, should be what are ways to determine there exists decompositions $n = ab = cd$ such that  $a >1$, $b>1$, $c > 1$ and $d > 1$, $B$ has size $a \times c$ and $C$ has size $b \times d$, such that $A = B \otimes C$. I am interested only in conditions of existence (or conditions of non-existence) that applies on $A$. There is no need to give conditions on how to find $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $B$ or $C$.
